# Detect Keyboard Event in C

Tags: c, keyboard

How can I detect keyboard event in C language without using third party libraries? Should I use signal handling?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's not a standard way, but these should get you started.

Windows:

```
getch();
```

Unix:

Use this code from W. Richard Stevens' Unix Programming book to set your terminal in raw mode, and then use read().

```
static struct termios   save_termios;
static int              term_saved;

int tty_raw(int fd) {       /* RAW! mode */
    struct termios  buf;

    if (tcgetattr(fd, &save_termios) < 0) /* get the original state */
        return -1;

    buf = save_termios;

    buf.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG);
                    /* echo off, canonical mode off, extended input
                       processing off, signal chars off */

    buf.c_iflag &= ~(BRKINT | ICRNL | ISTRIP | IXON);
                    /* no SIGINT on BREAK, CR-toNL off, input parity
                       check off, don't strip the 8th bit on input,
                       ouput flow control off */

    buf.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
                    /* clear size bits, parity checking off */

    buf.c_cflag |= CS8;
                    /* set 8 bits/char */

    buf.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST);
                    /* output processing off */

    buf.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;  /* 1 byte at a time */
    buf.c_cc[VTIME] = 0; /* no timer on input */

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSAFLUSH, &buf) < 0)
        return -1;

    term_saved = 1;

    return 0;
}


int tty_reset(int fd) { /* set it to normal! */
    if (term_saved)
        if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSAFLUSH, &save_termios) < 0)
            return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What about good old [kbhit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c(VS.80).aspx) ? If I understand the question correctly this will work. [Here](http://linux-sxs.org/programming/kbhit.html) is the kbhit implementation on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Standard C does not have any facilities for detecting keyboard events, unfortunately. You have to rely on platform-specific extensions. Signal handling wont help you.

Answer (score 3):

You really should use third party libraries.  There's definitely no platform-independent way to do it in ANSI C.  Signal handling is not the way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to answer, but:

The basic idea is to set the terminal to non-canonical mode so that you can read each keypress individually.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void setNonCanonicalMode() {
    struct termios term;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &term);
    term.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &term);
}

void resetCanonicalMode() {
    struct termios term;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &term);
    term.c_lflag |= ICANON | ECHO;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &term);
}
```

This should suffice.

Comment: *"I'm a little late to answer"* - Yes, like 15 years. Hope it wasn't urgent.  :-)