# Keyboard handler in C

Tags: c, linux, keyboard

In C, how can I write a program that tells me what keys are pressed? For example, it should output

```
You pressed F1 key
You pressed ESC key
You released F1 key
```

to the Linux console and end the program if for example both F1 and q keys are pressed down.

I tried

```
#include <curses.h>  // required

int r,c,  // current row and column (upper-left is (0,0))
    nrows,  // number of rows in window
    ncols;  // number of columns in window

void draw(char dc)

{  move(r,c);  // curses call to move cursor to row r, column c
   delch();  insch(dc);  // curses calls to replace character under cursor by dc
   refresh();  // curses call to update screen
   r++;  // go to next row
   // check for need to shift right or wrap around
   if (r == nrows)  {
      r = 0;
      c++;
      if (c == ncols) c = 0;
   }
}

main()

{  int i;  char d;
   WINDOW *wnd;

   wnd = initscr();  // curses call to initialize window
   cbreak();  // curses call to set no waiting for Enter key
   noecho();  // curses call to set no echoing
   getmaxyx(wnd,nrows,ncols);  // curses call to find size of window
   clear();  // curses call to clear screen, send cursor to position (0,0)
   refresh();  // curses call to implement all changes since last refresh

   r = 0; c = 0;
   while (1)  {
      d = getch();  // curses call to input from keyboard
      if (d == 'q') break;  // quit?
      draw(d);  // draw the character
   }

   endwin();  // curses call to restore the original window and leave

}
```

but it has problems with for example recognizing shift keys and valgrind said

```
==11693==    still reachable: 59,676 bytes in 97 blocks
```

Comment: I tried ncurses but the valgrind said I had some memory leaks and my code didn't recognize all keys.

Comment: This is way too broad, unless you have some code which you have tried you should delete this or move it to programmers Stack Exchange. If you do have code. Please, edit it into the question so we can see how far you have got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that this is not a C question; the answer is Linux-specific.  The C language does not offer a keyboard API.

To detect both key presses and releases you have to go deeper than

- the default behaviour of the Linux terminal driver (the so-called "cooked" mode), which lets you read characters a line at a time, using functions such as `getc` and `scanf`, and also
- the driver's so-called "raw" mode, which delivers to your application each key pressed, as used by modern editors and shells, and provided by the [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) API.

You do that by looking at input events.  See the header [input.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/input.h), a [corresponding article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/6429/print), and [an example of its use](http://rico-studio.com/linux/read-and-write-to-a-keyboard-device/).  Note that through this API you get lower level information: key scan codes, instead of ASCII or Unicode codes, and key-down (`EV_KEY`), key-up (`EV_REL`)  events rather than key presses.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily detect "classic" input (letters, digits and symbols) with a simple `scanf`/`printf` (you should get the code of your input in [Unicode](http://codepoints.net/), [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded).

For the "special" keys: have a look [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220818/detect-keyboard-event-in-c).

It seems there is no standard way to do this, but some links are given to third party library that can hopefully help.