# how to get Return key press event?

Tags: c, keyboard-events

I'm coding a console editor in C. I'm using CodeLite Editor on Windows. I want to insert a newline `('\n')` when the user presses Return (Enter) key. I want to accomplish this goal with `getchar()` function is that possible?
I need it because I want to increment the y axis variable.
Code I'm trying on :

```
int X = 0; // X-axis
int Y = 0; // Y-axis
char key = getchar();
if (key=='sth') // Here I want to perform my check 
{
    //Do Something
    ++Y;
}
```

Update : 
If it has a code like : `'\x45'` for example post it in the comments plz!!!

Comment: I'm inspired from this [page](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/78802-martyr2s-mega-project-ideas-list/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to implement an editor, you will quickly find that `getchar()` is not the way to interpret keyboard events.  In this very simplistic example, where all you might do is wait for a single keystroke of input that either is or is not a newline, your program will work if you change 'sth' (an abbreviation for "something"?) to `'\n'`.  However, as your editor becomes more complicated, you will want to have an actual event handler that can detect any sort of keyboard events and can asynchronously deal with them.  `getchar()` is not the way to do that.

This answer from 7 years ago shows that (1) you can go a limited distance with `getch()` (and `getchar()`), but (2) a far larger number of people agree that it's no substitute for a real event handler: [Detect Keyboard Event in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220818/detect-keyboard-event-in-c)

Comment: if you see the page you are referring to you will see for windows they say I should use `getch` , however getch isn't a part of Standard library so I shouldn't use it

Comment: You shouldn't not use it _just_ because it's not part of the standard library, but you're right to be aware/concerned that it isn't.  However, some things _aren't_ standardised, so sometimes you just have to go with what works (and get into all kinds of "interesting" challenges if you need it to be multiplatform).